# R ts object plot x-axis labeling seems shifted

Tags: r, time-series

When plotting a ts object in R the x-axis labels seem to be shifted, based on how I'm interpreting it. Could someone point out how to correctly interpret the x-axis?

Example:

Taking an example of sample data as used in the ts() documentation

```r
set.seed(123)
gnp = ts(cumsum(1 + round(rnorm(10), 2)), start = c(1954, 7), frequency = 12)
print(gnp)
       Jan   Feb   Mar   Apr May Jun   Jul   Aug   Sep   Oct   Nov   Dec
1954                                  0.44  1.21  3.77  4.84  5.97  8.69
1955 10.15  9.88 10.19 10.74
```

In the printed output above, things seem ok, the series starts from July (i.e. 7) 1954.

Next, I plot the time-series and add two vertical line. One solid at 1954 + (7/12), and another dashed at 1954 + (6/12).

```r
plot(gnp, type = "o", pch = 19)
abline(v = 1954 + (7/12), col = "red")
abline(v = 1954 + (6/12), col = "blue", lty = "dashed")
```

The output looks like this:
[image]

I was expecting that since the time-series start from July i.e. 7, the first data-point would lie on 1954+(7/12). What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Look into ts properties `tsp`

```
tsp(gnp)
# [1] 1954.50 1955.25   12.00
```

it shows a ts starting 1954.50, ending 1955.25 and freq 12.00 which indicates a sequence.

Since you only specified 10 values, what you're looking for is

```
seq.int(1954.50, 1955.25, length.out=10)
# [1] 1954.500000 1954.583333 1954.666667 1954.750000 1954.833333 1954.916667
# [7] 1955.000000 1955.083333 1955.166667 1955.250000
```

i.e.

```
n <- 10
gnp <- ts(cumsum(1 + round(rnorm(n), 2)), start = c(1954, 7), frequency = 12)
plot(gnp, type = "o", pch = 19)
Map(abline, v=do.call(seq.int, as.list(tsp(gnp) + c(0, 0, n - 12)) |> setNames(c('from', 'to', 'len'))),
    col=rainbow(n))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. The mention of tsp(gnp) and the output it gives highlighted where I was wrong in my assumption.

Answer (score 0):

Answering it based on the pointer I got from the previous response.

"*I was expecting that since the time-series start from July i.e. 7, the first data-point would lie on 1954+(7/12). What am I missing?*"

Expecting that July corresponds to 1954 + (7/12) is incorrect.

Consider the same example but when the time-series starts from January instead
of July. Now note that tsp(gnp) mentions the start of the series as 1954 and not 1954 + (1/12). This makes sense. Hence in the previous example the expectation should be that the first data point would lie on 1954 + (7-1)/12 - which indeed is what the plot is saying. The x-axis is the offset from the start of the year.

```
set.seed(123)
gnp = ts(cumsum(1 + round(rnorm(10), 2)), start = c(1954, 1), frequency = 12)
print(gnp)
       Jan   Feb   Mar   Apr   May   Jun   Jul   Aug   Sep   Oct
1954  0.44  1.21  3.77  4.84  5.97  8.69 10.15  9.88 10.19 10.74
tsp(gnp)
[1] 1954.00 1954.75   12.00
```